# Проблема запуска Intellij IDEA от root по RDP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rdp

Цепляюсь с win10 на ubuntu по RDP. При попытке открыть IDEA от рута ругается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

От пользователя работает. Подскажите, что подкрутить?

Comment: от рута гуишные приложение так легко не запускаются.  запустите от имени пользователься. зачем именно от рута?

Comment: Сгенерированные файлы в сетевую папку льются только когда идея запущена от рута, не знаю почему. От пользователя идея открывается

Comment: дайте вашему пользователью доступ в эту папку, чтобы тоже смог туда залить

Answer (score 0):

вот это не помогло ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t
советуют сделать

```
unset DISPLAY
```

Comment: да, я пробовал, не помогло